# jhipster/spring boot - Error occurred while trying to proxy request

Tags: node.js, spring, security, jhipster

I am getting a bunch of nodejs errors when I try to run my jhipster generated react webapp. I am running this project on `macos` with `node 10.4.1` and `yarn 1.7.0`. Here's the exact error:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /management/info from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /management/info from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

There might be something afoul happening with my computer.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This error means browsersync/webpack could not connect to the backend java which is on port 8080 for proxying API calls: the spring boot application must be running before you do "yarn start". You must run both "./mvnw" and "yarn start". See [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/) and webpack/webpack.dev.js file

Comment: I am running the server as well as the dockerized database. What settings in the firewall can block these ports?

Comment: Firewall is not blocking anything i guess.